# Writing Complex Equations in HTML?

Tags: html

Is there a way to write equations like the one I wrote here? Without manually
writing all the 1 height symbols? like

I want to Visualize `Simplify [{(-6^7)^8*[(21/1)/(22/1)]}^7]^9` In equation form like here: [symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/simplify-calculator/simplify%20%5Cleft%5B%5Cleft%5C%7B%5Cleft(-6%5E%7B7%7D%5Cright)%5E%7B8%7D%5Ccdot%5Cfrac%7B%5Cfrac%7B21%7D%7B1%7D%7D%7B%5Cfrac%7B22%7D%7B1%7D%7D%5Cright%5C%7D%5E%7B7%7D%5Cright%5D%5E%7B9%7D)
but like is there an HTML or Javascript method of automatically writing out complex equations like this?

Comment: _1 height symbols?_ you mean `^` caret?

Comment: You may be interested in MathML - markup language for displaying math.  MathJax may also be of interest. https://www.mathjax.org/

Comment: @dmb no I mean... I dont want the 1 letter high equations like the one I typed out, I want them to be more "good looking" to the point that life... Parenthesis symbols will get larger when there is a larger content inside like how symbolab expands symbols, moves them, and adds special features.

Comment: like* sorry, Im terrible at typing sometimes